# Postgres: Want to SELECT data when user exists, else INSERT user

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

Still getting the hang of PostgreSQL (Using PostgreSQL-12, so any advice is **very** much appreciated.

I have an application that allows the user to save and create playlists of songs.

**My tables are:** users, playlists, songs
Then I have **two junction tables:** user_playlist, playlist_song

I have a query that when given a userid will return all of the songs, from that user's first playlist (app defaults to first playlist on login), and it currently works how I want it to.

My next issue to tackle is that I want to now combine that query, with a second, that would add the userid to the user table if it didn't currently exist.

So the flow would be user logins in, then on login a userid is sent to my db.
In my database I want to check if that userid already exists, if it does I want the SELECT query that return songs to execute, but if that userid does not exist, I want to insert the userid into my user table

I've read about 10 StackOverflow solutions trying to tweak them to work for me, but haven't had any luck. I'm not sure if I should post all of the things I've already tried or not.

```
$$ BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE userid = '1') THEN

        SELECT
          s.songid,
          s.title,
          s.artists,
          s.album,
          s.year,
          s.duration,
          s.url,
          ps.songOrder
        FROM
          playlist_song ps
        JOIN
          songs s
        ON
          ps.songid = s.songid
        JOIN
          playlists p
        ON
          ps.playlistid = p.playlistid
        WHERE
          p.playlistid = (
            SELECT
              p.playlistid
            FROM
              user_playlist up
            JOIN
              playlists p
            ON
              up.playlistid = p.playlistid
            JOIN
              users u
            ON
              up.userid = u.userid
            WHERE
              u.userid = '1'
            LIMIT 1
          )
        ORDER BY ps.songOrder;


    ELSE
      INSERT INTO users (userid, username) VALUES ('1', 'Haley')
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

This is the error it is currently giving me when I test it in PG admin:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

So I then added RETURN to my SELECT and the error changed to

```
LINE 5:         RETURN (SELECT
                       ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 98
```

Adding RETURN QUERY gave the error was Cannot use return query in a non-setof function

Adding RETURN SETOF gave the error was RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void

I've been stuck on this for a day and a half and at this point and don't want to break it up into multiple calls to the db unless it's not possible (my pride needs to squash this bugger)

I can't tell you how much your help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
      userid TEXT NOT NULL,
      username TEXT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT u_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (userid)
    );


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (
      playlistid SERIAL NOT NULL,
      playlistname TEXT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT p_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (playlistid)

    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs (
      songid SERIAL NOT NULL,
      url TEXT,
      href TEXT,
      title TEXT,
      artists TEXT,
      album TEXT,
      year integer,
      duration integer,
        CONSTRAINT s_pk PRIMARY KEY (songid)
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_playlist (
      userid TEXT,
      playlistid INTEGER,
        CONSTRAINT u_up_fk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(userid),
        CONSTRAINT p_up_fk FOREIGN KEY (playlistid) REFERENCES playlists(playlistid)
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlist_song (
      playlistid INTEGER,
      songid INTEGER,
      songOrder INTEGER,
        CONSTRAINT p_ps_fk FOREIGN KEY (playlistid) REFERENCES playlists(playlistid),
        CONSTRAINT s_ps_fk FOREIGN KEY (songid) REFERENCES songs(songid)
    );
```

**Next attempt**:

```
CREATE TYPE songs_type AS (
          songid integer,
          title character varying(25),
          artists character varying(25),
          album character varying(25),
          year integer,
          duration integer,
          url character varying(25),
          songOrder integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func() RETURNS songs_type AS
$$
DECLARE results_record songs_type;
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM auxium.users WHERE userid = '1') THEN

      SELECT
          s.songid,
          s.title,
          s.artists,
          s.album,
          s.year,
          s.duration,
          s.url,
          ps.songOrder


        INTO
          results_record.songid,
          results_record.title,
          results_record.artists,
          results_record.album,
          results_record.year,
          results_record.duration,
          results_record.url,
          results_record.songOrder
        FROM
          auxium.playlist_song ps
        JOIN
          auxium.songs s
        ON
          ps.songid = s.songid
        JOIN
          auxium.playlists p
        ON
          ps.playlistid = p.playlistid
        WHERE
          p.playlistid = (
            SELECT
              p.playlistid
            FROM
              auxium.user_playlist up
            JOIN
              auxium.playlists p
            ON
              up.playlistid = p.playlistid
            JOIN
              auxium.users u
            ON
              up.userid = u.userid
            WHERE
              u.userid = '1'
            LIMIT 1
          )
        ORDER BY ps.songOrder;


    ELSE
      INSERT INTO auxium.users (userid, username) VALUES ('1', 'Haley')
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    END IF;
    return results_record;
END;
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can you share input and expected output data? It would be helpful to provide a Fiddle for you to try.

Comment: I can't really comment on the SQL nitty-gritty, but: isn't it a bit odd to have a function that *either* returns a set of rows, *or* inserts a row and doesn't return anything? Wouldn't you want it to always return a set of rows (which would have zero rows in it in the case of a new user)?

Comment: @TurePålsson I tried going that route also and just wasn't able to get that working either, but that would work for what I'm doing too if I could figure it out!

Comment: @KumarRohit 
Input will be: userid (String) and username (string)

Output will be:
          s.songid (INT from songs table)
          s.title (TEXT from songs table)
          s.artists (TEXT from songs table)
          s.album (TEXT from songs table)
          s.year (INT from songs table)
          s.duration (INT from songs table)
          s.url (TEXT from songs table)
          ps.songOrder (INT from playlist_song table)

I'll update the original post with the schemas

Answer (score 0):

Create type and then return it.

I have created users(userid,username) table and then created type with same schema as i am selecting the same. You will have to change it to the columns you are selecting(while creating TYPE).

It is working fine.

```
CREATE TYPE users_type AS (userid integer,username character varying(10));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun() RETURNS users_type AS
$$ 
DECLARE result_record users_type;
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE userid = 1) THEN
         SELECT userid,username into result_record.userid,result_record.username from users;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO users (userid, username) VALUES (1, 'Haley');
    END IF;
    return result_record;
END;
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
So when I'm recreating this and run it, I'm getting the error -->  
 _error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement_ in my server

Comment: Added the recreated code. Please let me know if it looks wrong! Thank you again

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine at my end. What values are you trying to insert? it should not be '\'.